# spring cloud config server from github

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

**i am confused by this problem deeply.**

**this is application.properties :**

```
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=7001
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
```

**this is application main:**

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
  }
}
```

but the response time is so long, actually last year it worked well.but now:(spring boot version:any(try many versions),as well add git.username&password)
the result is so long time and no response.
 of course ,if through native ways to get config file,it is ok!

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I'd suspect there is something in your environment.

Comment: `curl http://localhost:7001/foo/db` this url, except nothing. in pom.xml:spring-boot-starter-parent,spring-boot-starter-test,spring-cloud-config-server,spring-cloud-dependencies,spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Comment: If you set `LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=DEBUG`, are there obvious pauses in the output, or surprising entries?   And I assume that ```time git clone https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo``` takes only a second or two?

Comment: thanks, i got it and it did have so many surprising entries.